# How to give horizontal gradient color to button in ios

Tags: ios, uikit, gradient, uicolor

How to give horizontal gradient color to button in ios?

I am trying to give button gradient color blue in horizontal direction, but not getting output properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
{
    UIColor *transBgColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    UIColor *black = [UIColor blackColor];
    CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    maskLayer.opacity = 0.8;
    maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)black.CGColor, 
    (id)transBgColor.CGColor, (id)transBgColor.CGColor, (id)black.CGColor, nil];

    // Horizontal - commenting these two lines will make the gradient vertical
    maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

    NSNumber *gradTopStart = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *gradTopEnd = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4];
    NSNumber *gradBottomStart = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6];
    NSNumber *gradBottomEnd = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    maskLayer.locations = @[gradTopStart, gradTopEnd, gradBottomStart, gradBottomEnd];

    maskLayer.bounds = container.bounds;
    maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    [container.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try this code

```
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                             nil];
[yourbtn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: its color is coming in vertical direction not in horizontal

Comment: set its gradient location , start point and end point as :=>  gradient.locations = [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]

/* make it horizontal */
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5)

Comment: Now it is coming in horizontal direction but it is showing one unwanted blue color layer at the bottom of button.

Comment: You should go to Settings > General > Accessibility and turn off Button Shapes and then reRun the app it will remove the unwanted blue layer

Answer (score 0):

This will let you insert an horizontal gradient for your button, where first color is on the left, second color is on the right:

```
extension UIView {
    func insertHorizontalGradient(_ color1: UIColor, _ color2: UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        gradient.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        gradient.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

You may want to keep a reference to the layer in order to resize its frame, otherwise be sure to call it only after the button frame is definitive.